# How can I get past somebody's password lock screen without them knowing?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s

My daughter changed her lock screen password on her phone. She has learned how to keep me from unlocking it. So I am asking, is there away I can get her password with out her realising it? Or can I get inside her phone without changing her current password? Her phone is a "METROPCS Samsung Galaxy Avant".

Answer (score 1):

No theres no actual way of doing it unless you perform a factory reset from recovery mode which would be completely usless if you wanted to see things that shes got on there. Unless she has it all on an sd card.